# Image forcing down list even though using inline block

Tags: html, css

***HTML :***

```
<nav class="header"> <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" class="logo"></a>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li id="a" class=""><a href="#"><span></span>A</a>
        </li>
        <li id="b" class=""><a href="#"><span></span>B</a>
        </li>
        <li id="account" class="right"> <a href="/admin/profile"><span></span>Test Test</a>

            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="/users/logout">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

From a previous question I was told to use inline-block to get the list to sit on the same line as the image (logo). however when I make the image the full height of the header it still drops the list down. What am I doing wrong?

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/9/)

Comment: We need to see your CSS to be able to help you. You need to give your `.dropdown` a position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in `.navigation`  class `position` from `relative` to `absolute`.

```
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/11/)

Comment: Thank you, that looks great, but why doesn't the "test test" sit on the right anymore since it is floated?

Comment: hmm Is on the right. As your first fiddle. You mean to the edge right?

Comment: On my screen here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/11/embedded/result/ everything is aligned to the left when actually the cog and "test test" should be floated right

Comment: Really can't understand what you mean. Can you post an image how it suppose to like "test test" ?